# Erlang:ipv6 value to octet binary value

Tags: erlang

I want to convert IPv6 value which is in HEX to Octet binary.

Ipv6 : 2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348

is there any example format how erlang octet binary looks and how i can convert this.

Thanks in advance
Priya

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function [`inet:parse_ipv6_address/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#parse_ipv6_address-1) to parse the address into integers:

```
> {ok, {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}} = inet:parse_ipv6_address("2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348").
{ok,{8193,3512,34211,2259,4889,35374,880,29512}}
```

Then you can combine those integers into a single binary:

```
> <<A:16, B:16, C:16, D:16, E:16, F:16, G:16, H:16>>.
<<32,1,13,184,133,163,8,211,19,25,138,46,3,112,115,72>>
```

Each number shown in that result is an octet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lot of methods If you want to do it manually, I will give you one of them, using anonymous function.

```
% IPv6 addresses are split in 8 parts, each parts 
% are coded in hexadecimal, starting from 0 to ffff.
% In decimal: 0 to 65535.
Ip6Parser = fun % if we match empty bitstring, we return the value
                F(<<>>, Return, Buffer) -> 
                  Convert = erlang:binary_to_integer(Buffer, 16),
                  <<Return/bitstring, Convert:16>>;

                % if we match semi-column (:) char, we switch to
                % another ipv6 part
                F(<<":", Rest/bitstring>>, Return, <<>>) ->
                  F(Rest, <<Return/bitstring, 0:16>>, <<>>);
                F(<<":", Rest/bitstring>>, Return, Buffer) -> 
                  Convert = erlang:binary_to_integer(Buffer, 16),
                  F(Rest, <<Return/bitstring, Convert:16>>, <<>>);

                % currently, we use ascii representation, coded
                % on 8bits. We need to check if this byte is a
                % correct number (see guards)
                F(<<Char:8, Rest/bitstring>>, Return, Buffer) 
                  when Char >= $0 andalso Char =< $9 orelse
                       Char >= $a andalso Char =< $f orelse
                       Char >= $A andalso Char =< $F ->
                    F(Rest, Return, <<Buffer/bitstring, Char>>);

                % if we don't match hexadecimal representation
                % we return an error.
                F(Rest, Return, Buffer) ->
                  {error, badvalue, {Rest, Return, Buffer}}
             end.
```

We can use this code like this:

```
Ip6Parser(<<"2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348">>, <<>>, <<>>).
```

And will return:

```
<<32,1,13,184,133,163,8,211,19,25,138,46,3,112,115,72>>
```

To be sure, we can check if the first 16bits are well encoded:

```
<<First:16, Rest/bitstring>> = 
    Ip6Parser(<<"2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348">>, <<>>, <<>>).
First
% return 8193 in decimal
```

If you want to check this value in hexadecimal:

```
erlang:integer_to_list(First, 16).
% will return "2001"
```

You can find more information on all aspect here:

- [Bit Syntax in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html)
- [Pattern Matching in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/patterns.html)
- [Anonymous Functions (Funs) in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/funs.html)
- [`erlang:binary_to_integer`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_integer-1)
- [`erlang:integer_to_list`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#integer_to_list-2)
- [`erlang:integer_to_binary`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#integer_to_binary-2)

**Note**: this code will work only on Erlang R18 and R19. If you want to execute it on lower release, you'll need to create dedicated function, or add one argument to this lambda function (reference to current lambda function), something like that:

```
Ipv6 = fun (Bitstring, Return, Buffer, Fun)
         when is_function(Fun) ->
            Fun(Bitstring, Return, Buffer, Fun).
```

Have fun! ;)